# Incomplete printing of the $\mathscr{H}$ symbol

Tags: printing

I don't know exactly if this is the correct place to ask this, but, for some reason the PDF files generated by latex are not printing correctly, more specifically the $\mathscr{H}$ symbol is being printed with its upper part missing. In principle this could be a problem with the printer that I am using, but I think it is some problem with the way the latex is compiling the file.

To begin with, the compiled PDF is correct, there is no part missing on the upper part of the symbol $\mathscr{H}$, so thinking it was a printing problem I decided to try to print several scaled versions of the letter $\mathscr{H}$, here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\begin{document}
\[\mathscr{H},\,\,\scalebox{1.1}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.2}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.3}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.4}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.5}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.6}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.7}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.8}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{1.9}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\]

\[\,\,A,\scalebox{2.0}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.1}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.2}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.3}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.4}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.5}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.6}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.7}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\]
\[\,\,\scalebox{2.8}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{2.9}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.0}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.1}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.2}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.3}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.4}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\]
\[\,\,\scalebox{3.5}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.6}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.7}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.8}{$\mathscr{H}$ },\,\,\scalebox{3.9}{$\mathscr{H}$ },A\]
\end{document}
```

Here is a image of the resulting PDF page:

[image]

And here is a picture of the PDF page printed:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't seem to be a problem with the thickness of the line of the letter, as the last scaled $\mathscr{H}$ is way thicker than the A and it shows the same problem as the regular sized one.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe start by testing on another printer?

Comment: It's might be Printer issue, some of the Printers doesn't accept the font size below 6pt

Comment: @MadyYuvi, but the A prints all right, look at the last line, the thickness of the lines in  $\mathscr{H}$ are greather than that of the lines of that last $A$. I think this might be a problem when the PDF is being discretized to be printed, which means that it probably is tracable back to the PDF generation process.

Comment: Also the printer that this was printed at was a big HP professional printer that is present in my department.

Comment: Most of the Printer accepts the line thickness should be atleast 0.25pt

Comment: @MadyYuvi  Yes, but as you can see it is not a question of line thickness.